# NIFI 1.9 Flow File stuck on Cluster Mode

Tags: apache-nifi

I have migrated my standalone to cluster mode with 2 nodes.
Machines are having 76 cores and 2 threads per core and hyper threading is
also enabled.

And I started my flow using round robin as load balancer. And I found the
out 8K flow files, 5K flow file are stuck and nothing is going forward.

Processor Details

**ListSFTP(1 thread,Primary) -->RouteOnAttribute{20 threads,10000,All Nodes}
---> FetchSFTP{20 threads,10000,All Nodes}**

**nifi-properties file**

```
nifi.bored.yield.duration=10 millis
nifi.cluster.flow.election.max.candidates=2
nifi.cluster.flow.election.max.wait.time=2 mins
nifi.cluster.is.node=true
nifi.cluster.load.balance.comms.timeout=30s
nifi.cluster.load.balance.connections.per.node=4
nifi.cluster.load.balance.host=zzzzz-ccvcc.ivvvv.ccc.XXX
nifi.cluster.load.balance.max.thread.count=100
nifi.cluster.load.balance.port=6342
nifi.cluster.node.address=zzzzz-ccvcc.ivvvv.ccc.XXX
nifi.cluster.node.connection.timeout=30 sec
nifi.cluster.node.event.history.size=25
nifi.cluster.node.max.concurrent.requests=400
nifi.cluster.node.protocol.max.threads=300
nifi.cluster.node.protocol.port=9088
nifi.cluster.node.protocol.threads=50
nifi.cluster.node.read.timeout=30 sec
nifi.cluster.protocol.heartbeat.interval=5 sec

nifi.queue.backpressure.count=40000
nifi.queue.backpressure.size=5 GB
nifi.queue.swap.threshold=40000
```

NIFI logs in DEBUG mode

2019-07-19 17:42:18,878 DEBUG [Timer-Driven Process Thread-182]
o.a.n.c.s.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent Yielding
LookupAttribute[id=fbedd9e2-5fd5-370d-85ac-fd85a66cb907] due to No work to
do
2019-07-19 17:42:18,878 DEBUG [Timer-Driven Process Thread-182]
org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine A flow controller execution task
'java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@579f68a4'
has been cancelled.
2019-07-19 17:42:18,854 DEBUG [Timer-Driven Process Thread-433]
org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine A flow controller execution task
'java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@f38d55a'
has been cancelled.
2019-07-19 17:42:18,854 DEBUG [Timer-Driven Process Thread-50]
org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine A flow controller execution task
'java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@37fdf676'
has been cancelled.
2019-07-19 17:42:18,878 DEBUG [Timer-Driven Process Thread-433]
o.a.n.c.s.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent Yielding
ReplaceText[id=e1dbc039-c2ec-369e-9002-e0ab0a4ffa49] due to No work to do
2019-07-19 17:42:18,878 DEBUG [Timer-Driven Process Thread-50]
o.a.n.c.s.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent Yielding
StandardFunnel[id=3b287ed8-0254-3312-a9d0-1114cc44a142] due to No work to do
2019-07-19 17:42:18,878 DEBUG [Timer-Driven Process Thread-433]
org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine A flow controller execution task
'java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@ef41461'
has been cancelled.
2019-07-19 17:42:18,878 DEBUG [Timer-Driven Process Thread-50]
org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine A flow controller execution task
'java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@3a783c59'
has been cancelled.
2019-07-19 17:42:18,854 DEBUG [Timer-Driven Process Thread-153]
o.a.n.c.s.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent Yielding
ExecuteStreamCommand[id=35f9577a-22c3-33c5-bb3d-6932743d763f] due to No work
to do
2019-07-19 17:42:18,854 DEBUG [Timer-Driven Process Thread-98]
org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine A flow controller execution task
'java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@2803105e'
has been cancelled.
2019-07-19 17:42:18,878 DEBUG [Timer-Driven Process Thread-153]
org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine A flow controller execution task
'java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@a01dc68'
has been cancelled.
2019-07-19 17:42:18,878 DEBUG [Timer-Driven Process Thread-98]
o.a.n.c.s.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent Yielding
FetchHDFS[id=18df1d2f-0d84-38bd-a447-3a712e7220b3] due to Backpressure
Applied
2019-07-19 17:42:18,878 DEBUG [Timer-Driven Process Thread-98]
org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine A flow controller execution task
'java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@4fd425bc'
has been cancelled.
2019-07-19 17:42:18,854 DEBUG [Timer-Driven Process Thread-137]
org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine A flow controller execution task
'java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@68d5328e'
has been cancelled.

When switch back to do not load balance it works like charm.

I have tested with all the configuration but couldn't find anything
anywhere.

Even on listing queue which is having 5K files,doesn't show any flowfiles

Need Help..!!!!! May be I am missing something.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Which specific release are you on, 1.9.2?

Comment: Nifi 1.9.0 version

Comment: The description of the problem sounds closest to this issue - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-5919 but that is resolved in 1.9.0. It still might be worth trying 1.9.2 to make sure there weren't any bug fixes related to load balancing, there is actually a critical bug fix in 1.9.1 that you would want anyway :)

Comment: I will update NIFI version to 1.9.2 and I will check if it still exits.However I didn't find anything related to this issue in release notes of 1.9.1 and 1.9.2